# Why are my attributes being ignored on my User Control public properties?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a user control with a number of public properties of type string.  This means that they are exposed in the designer, where the user is able to populate them.

The problem is, the attributes on my properties are being ignored.  Here is an example:

```
    [Description("This doesn't appear")]
    [Editor(typeof(MultilineStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string Test { get; set; }
```

The Description attribute means that when the user clicks on the field in designer, the description shows in the properties window.  And the Editor attribute above means that in designer rather than the editor being a single line field, it becomes a multiline dropdown.  The problem is, neither of these happen.

It seems that all attributes are being ignored in my usercontrol.

Does anyone have a simple explanation as to why that might be?

Comment: Just curious: Have you run a full rebuild of your solution?

Comment: Yep, several times, as well as restarted VS2012 and the project.  I have also renamed the property several times to ensure that the most up to date version is being detected (ie. change the property from "Test" to "Test2").  No luck.

Comment: I think you need to add a `[Browsable(true)]` attribute in order for the property to be displayed in the properties window.